# Merge duplicate cases in match Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have come by this problem many times: I have a proof state in Coq that includes matches on both sides of an equality that are the same.

Is there a standard way to rewrite multiple matches into one?

Eg.

```
match expression_evaling_to_Z with
    Zarith.Z0 => something
    Zartih.Pos _ => something_else
    Zarith.Neg _ => something_else
end = yet_another_thing.
```

And if I destruct on `expresion_evaling_to_Z` I get two identical goals. I would like to find a way to get only one of the goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard solution is to define "a view" of your datatype using a type family that will introduce the proper conditions and cases when destructed. For your particular case, you could do:

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.

Inductive zero_view_spec : Z -> Type :=
| Z_zero  :                      zero_view_spec Z0
| Z_zeroN : forall z, z <> Z0 -> zero_view_spec z.

Lemma zero_viewP z : zero_view_spec z.
Proof. now destruct z; [constructor|constructor 2|constructor 2]. Qed.

Lemma U z : match z with
              Z0              => 0
            | Zpos _ | Zneg _ => 1
            end = 0.
Proof.
destruct (zero_viewP z).
Abort.
```

This is a common idiom in some libraries like math-comp, which provides special support for instantiating the `z` argument of the type family.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the `match` expression more succinctly:

```
match expression_evaling_to_Z with
  | Z0 => something
  | Zpos _ | Zneg _ => something_else
end = yet_another_thing.
```

But that will give you 3 subgoals when using `destruct`.

In this particular case we may use the fact that you actually need to distinguish the zero and non-zero cases, and it looks like a job for the `Z.abs_nat : Z -> nat` function.

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.BinIntDef.

match Z.abs_nat (expression_evaling_to_Z) with
  | O => something
  | S _ => something_else
end = yet_another_thing.
```

This will get you only two subcases, but you need to destruct on `Z.abs_nat (expression_evaling_to_Z)` or introduce a new variable. If you choose the 1st variant, then you'll probably need `destruct (...) eqn:Heq.` to put the equation into context.

Basically this approach is about finding a new datatype (or defining one) and a suitable function to map from the old type to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind typing you can use `replace` to replace the RHS with the LHS of your goal, which makes it trivial to solve, and then you just have to prove once that the rewrite is indeed ok.

```
Open Scope Z.
Lemma L a b :
  match a + b with
      Z0     => a + b
    | Zpos _ => b + a
    | Zneg _ => b + a
  end = a + b.
  replace (b+a) with (a+b). (* 1. replace the RHS with something trivially true *)
  destruct (a+b); auto.     (* 2. solve the branches in one fell swoop *)
  apply Z.add_comm.         (* 3. solve only once what is required for the two brances *)
Qed.
```

Perhaps you can use some Ltac-fu or other lemma to not have to type in the RHS manually too.